# PHP Syntax Error for some unknown reason

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Recently started to fix up some code on a old project, however i'm abit rusty and can't for the life of me see whats wrong with this code.. as far as I can see it looked fine but at 3.25am anything can be wrong!

**The Error:**

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'value' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

**The Code:**

```
    <?php
if ($post_rank == 0) {
    echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 1) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 2) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected" >2</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 3) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">3</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 4) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">4</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 5) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">5</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 6) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">6</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 7) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">7</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 8) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">8</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 9) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">9</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 10) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">10</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 11) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">11</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 12) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">12</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 13) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">13</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 14) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">14</option>';
} else if ($post_rank == 15) {
    echo '<option value="1" selected="selected">15</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `'<option value="0"` <-- wrong quotes

Comment: Your single quote is encapsulating the string so it can't be used for encapsulating the `value` attribute unless it is escaped. e.g. `value=\'0\'` or `value="0"`

Comment: Hey Thanks for the replies.. very quick! :) however I completly forgot to update the actual question to show value="0" not value='0' as the first option is actually what is being used. However with both the error stays the same. (including with \'s included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue,

```
echo '<option value='0' selected="selected">0</option>';
```

It should be

```
echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>';
                    ^ double quotes.
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the replies.. very quick! :) however I completly forgot to update the actual question to show value="0" not value='0' as the first option is actually what is being used.  However with both the error stays the same. (including with \'s included.

Comment: didnt get what exactly you r telling.

Comment: Check the updated script, it is the same as your "it should be" answer (like it actually was, I just forgot to update it on the copy /paste I did) and the error remains the same.

Comment: which is the error line??

Comment: The echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>'; line.

Comment: can you add little more code??

Comment: what im feeling in, `<?php` tag is already opened somewhere. try removing the `<?php` tag above the error line.

Comment: Hey, sorry here is the full code http://pastebin.com/A9a7mG9T - I should've added it to the actual post.

Comment: remove `<?php` above your `if()`.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to use the localhost code over the live code again :P here is the actual code : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xYuzyPqX

Comment: first close the echo with `;` before `if()`

Comment: Ah finally, closing the echo (that I completely forgot about) and adding a new echo' for the last part fixed the problem, many thanks! :)

Comment: Glad i could help you:)